# How do I freeze a column and header row at the same time with scrollbar on side of GridView in .net?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a `GridView`. It has many columns and thousands of rows, so I need it to be horizontally scrollable as well as vertically scrollable. I need to freeze a header with scrollable and first two columns with horizontally scrollable, so how to do that?

I searched a lot on the Internet and I did not find anything related to what I want. I used some of the tutorials about freezing the header and freezing columns individually, but couldn't find anything which allows both to work together. Please help me.

Comment: add some code samples that you tried

Comment: A grid view gets rendered as a html table in your page. Did you try searching for solutions relating to HTML tables?

Answer (score 0):

[Datatables Fixed Columns](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/)

```
$('#yourTableId').DataTable( {
    fixedColumns: true
} );
```

[Datatables Fixed Header](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/)

```
$('#yourTableId').DataTable( {
    fixedHeader: true
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            <div id="HeaderDiv" runat="server">
                                    </div>
                                    <%--Wrapper Div which will scroll the GridView--%>
                                    <div id="DataDiv" runat="server" style="overflow: auto; border: 1px solid black; width: 900px; height: 400px;"
                                        onscroll="Onscrollfnction();">
                                        <asp:GridView ID="gvemp" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EmptyDataText="No Record Found"
                                            OnRowDataBound="gvemp_RowDataBound">
 <Columns>
 </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

                                </div>



    function CreateGridHeader() {
                var DataDivObj = "";
                var DataGridObj = "";
                var HeaderDivObj = "";

                DataDivObj = document.getElementById('<%=DataDiv.ClientID %>');
                DataGridObj = document.getElementById('<%=gvemp.ClientID %>');
                HeaderDivObj = document.getElementById('<%=HeaderDiv.ClientID %>');


                //********* Creating new table which contains the header row ***********
                var HeadertableObj = HeaderDivObj.appendChild(document.createElement('table'));
                DataDivObj.style.paddingTop = '0px';
                var DataDivWidth = DataDivObj.clientWidth;
                DataDivObj.style.width = '2000px';
                //********** Setting the style of Header Div as per the Data Div ************
                HeaderDivObj.className = DataDivObj.className;
                HeaderDivObj.style.cssText = DataDivObj.style.cssText;
                //**** Making the Header Div scrollable. *****
                HeaderDivObj.style.overflow = 'auto';
                //*** Hiding the horizontal scroll bar of Header Div ****
                //*** this is because we have to scroll the Div along with the DataDiv.  
                HeaderDivObj.style.overflowX = 'hidden';
                //**** Hiding the vertical scroll bar of Header Div **** 
                HeaderDivObj.style.overflowY = 'hidden';
                HeaderDivObj.style.height = DataGridObj.rows[0].clientHeight + 'px';
                //**** Removing any border between Header Div and Data Div ****
                HeaderDivObj.style.borderBottomWidth = '0px';
                //********** Setting the style of Header Table as per the GridView ************
                HeadertableObj.className = DataGridObj.className;
                //**** Setting the Headertable css text as per the GridView css text 
                HeadertableObj.style.cssText = DataGridObj.style.cssText;
                HeadertableObj.border = '1px';
                HeadertableObj.rules = 'all';
                HeadertableObj.cellPadding = DataGridObj.cellPadding;
                HeadertableObj.cellSpacing = DataGridObj.cellSpacing;
                //********** Creating the new header row **********
                var Row = HeadertableObj.insertRow(0);
                Row.className = DataGridObj.rows[0].className;
                Row.style.cssText = DataGridObj.rows[0].style.cssText;
                Row.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
                //******** This loop will create each header cell *********
                for (var iCntr = 0; iCntr < DataGridObj.rows[0].cells.length - 4; iCntr++) {
                    if (iCntr != 1) {
    var align = "left";
                            var spanTag = Row.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
                            spanTag.innerHTML = DataGridObj.rows[0].cells[iCntr].innerHTML;
                            var width = 0;
                            //****** Setting the width of Header Cell **********
                            if (spanTag.clientWidth > DataGridObj.rows[1].cells[iCntr].clientWidth) {
                                width = spanTag.clientWidth;
                                align = DataGridObj.rows[1].cells[iCntr].align;
                            }
                            else {
                                width = DataGridObj.rows[1].cells[iCntr].clientWidth;
                                align = DataGridObj.rows[1].cells[iCntr].align;
                            }
                            if (iCntr <= DataGridObj.rows[0].cells.length - 2) {
                                spanTag.style.width = width + 'px';
                            }
                            else {
                                spanTag.style.width = width + 20 + 'px';
                            }
                            DataGridObj.rows[1].cells[iCntr].style.width = width + 'px';
                            //Assigning Alignment
                            spanTag.align = align;
           }
                }
            }
```

Comment: I see you have added some comments but a good quality answer would also contain some text at the top summarising what you've done, and why it solves the problem, and then pointing the reader towards the comments to understand the detail. I nearly did not see them, and also the code lacks context. Thanks.